# Degree of a Differential Equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $$\sin\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=x$$ what is the degree of the above differential equation? According to me it's degree is not defined as the equation is not polynomial in derivatives. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why you don't see it this way $\frac{dy}{dx}=\arcsin(x)$? Also, I don't think that the definition of the degree depends on the ODE to be a polynomial of derivatives. :)

Comment: According to me as you did will change the diff equation...it is not the same as original one..

Comment: One more thing sin is not invertible on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: About the invertability, you can consider a union of invertable sub-intervals of $\mathbb R$. However, these discussions are not needed for your question. The degree is simply $1$ and there is no need for the ODE to be a polynomial of derivatives. As far as I know the degree is defined as "the power of the highest order derivative."

Comment: No degree is defined as the power of highest order derivative if it is free from radicals and fractions as far as consider derivatives of dependent variables

Comment: Is there any radicals or fractions here? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after some discussions I came up with the idea to write the Taylor expansion of the left hand side. We know that the Taylor expansion of $\sin x$ at $x=0$ is

$$\sin x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$

Now, replace $x$ with $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to get

$$\sin \frac{dy}{dx} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} (\frac{dy}{dx})^{2k+1}$$

and hence the ODE will look like

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} (\frac{dy}{dx})^{2k+1}=x$$

so we may consider the degree to be **infinite**!

Comment: Are you sure that this won't mislead others from the real answer to this question? :)

Comment: @Evgeny: mmmm, I am not sure but I have seen such expressions in papers! OK, what do you think? :) In fact, the main problem is the definition of **degree** of an ODE

Comment: I think that everything is acceptable unless people won't decline solving or studying this equation as "first-order implicit ODE" :) however, the answer might really depend on the expression we use. All books that I have define the ODE as "an equation of form $F(x, y, y', \dots, y^{(n)})=0$; $n$ is finite and it is called _the order of equation_"...

Comment: @Evgeny: And what the books says about the **degree** (not order)? :)

Comment: Ah, I see now :) But I think that a lot of people have the same problem -- they (from time to time) mix degree with order :)